# How to return a user object from a request

Tags: typescript, typeorm

I want to return only the user object from the request.

```
public async getUserByHash(hash: IHash) {
    this.logger.log('Hash for check email geted');
    const user = await this.hashRepository.findOne({
        select: ['id', 'user'],
        relations: ['user'],
        where: hash,
    });
    return user;
}
```

The user variable now contains.

```
{
    id:2
    user: {
        id: 3, 
        email:"email@test.com",
        password:"12345678"
    }
}
```

I want to get only the user fields, namely his identifier and his email.

I tried to do like this, but get an error.

```
public async getUserByHash(hash: IHash) {
    this.logger.log('Hash for check email geted');
    const user = await this.hashRepository.findOne({
        select: ['user.id', 'user.email'],
        relations: ['user'],
        where: hash,
    });
    return user;
}
```

But I got an error.

> QueryFailedError: ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'distinctAlias.Hash_id' in 'field list'

How can I get only user fields, ID and email?

Comment: select used to set the main object fields, so I'd use userRepository and add the hash to it as relation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try lodash

```
import { pick as _pick } from 'lodash'; 

public async getUserByHash(hash: IHash) {
    this.logger.log('Hash for check email geted');

    const user = await this.hashRepository.findOne({
        select: ['id', 'user'],
        relations: ['user'],
        where: hash,
    });

    return _pick(user.user, ['id', 'email']);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try this one.

```
return user.user
```

Hope that works.

Comment: Yes, it works, but I could also write `const { user } = await ...`. But I do not need a user password. Do I have to delete it myself? Why can't I return only what I need?

Comment: I think you need to modify the user password schema and add 'select: false'